Is there a reason for usage of C representation of types in some SPL
For example, why is there COption when compared to the Native Rust primitives and the Rust native Option?
What's the advantage of having this?

The concept was to allow for programs written in C to easily interact with SPL programs. COption works nicely with a tagged union in C, where the enum discriminant is 4 bytes.
